# Unable to pass variable in AQL Json file by using Jfrog CLI

Tags: json, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang, jfrog-cli

By using AQL query and Jfrog CLI, we are planning to find out the expired artifacts in our artifactory enterprise version.

For that I would like to pass a variable in AQL Json file to delete the artifacts by using Jfrog CLI.

Because the value of the variable will not be a static value and it will dynamic. So I need to pass a variable into Json file and the below highlighted variable I need to use.

**Command:**

```
./jfrog rt del --spec /xxxxxxxx.json --dry-run=true --quiet=true
```

**xxxx.Json:**

```
{
 "files":[
  {
     "aql":{
        "items.find":{
           "type":"file",
           "$or":[
              {
                 "$and":[
                    {
                       "stat.downloads":{
                          "$eq":null
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "modified":{
                          "$before":"1s"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "@retention.RetDate":{
                          "$lt":"$RetDate"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "$and":[
                    {
                       "stat.downloads":{
                          "$gt":"0"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "stat.downloaded":{
                          "$before":"1s"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "modified":{
                          "$before":"1s"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "@retention.RetDate":{
                          "$lt":"$RetDate"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want variables in your spec file, you should define the variables in the call:

```
./jfrog rt del --spec /xxxxxxxx.json --spec-vars "RetDate=2018-01-01" --dry-run=true --quiet=true
```

And unless I am mistaken, the variables are identified as ${key} in the spec file, so something like

```
                [...]
                {
                   "@retention.RetDate":{
                      "$lt":"${RetDate}"
                   }
                }
                [...]
```

Does it help your test case?